# Laravel datatabse cache : eloquent use a lot of RAM insted of DB facade

Tags: laravel, eloquent, redis

I want to cache the full table ,

when I use eloquent it use a lot of RAM to create or get the cached result.

```
$users = Cache::remember('cache_with_eloquent', 60 * 5, function () {
       return User::all();
});
```

**128MB** RAM used

[image]

them same code , but I used the DB facade instead of eloquent .
It uses only **44MB**

```
$users = Cache::remember('cache_with_db_facade', 60 * 5, function () {
       return DB::table('users')->get()
});
```

[image]

can someone explain the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Both have the same SQL query,

But this one `return User::all();` or `return User::get();` will run model related functionality, e.i. attribute casting, data transformation etc.

while the builder `return DB::table('users')->get();` will spit the result directly whatever the SQL will throw at him.

Comment: And `DB` facade will return a collection of arrays instead of models

Comment: well query Builder returns a Collection of `stdClass` objects ... a `select` directly on the Connection would return an array of `stdClass` objects

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent provides object oriented interface to interact with database. Therefore, objects are cached in RAM by default to ensure data consistency.

The DB facade provides a interface only to build raw SQL queries. So it doesn't eat memory like Eloquent.

Comment: And `DB` facade will return a collection of arrays instead of models